# Save List<> into Firestore. Android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have Account class and List object there. So, I need to store that List in my firestore, what should I do? Also how to get that array from firestore?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I didn't try anything. Database is empty as I don't know how to save arrays or List<>s into that...

Answer (score 0):

CLASS

```
public class Account {
    String desc;
    List<ObjXXX>  listObjXXX = new ArrayList<>();
```

STORE

```
DatabaseReference newPostRef = dbRef1.push();
String child = newPostRef.getKey(); 
Account item = new Account("XXX", listObj);
newPostRef.setValue(item);
```

GET

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(child);
                ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                        Account account = (Account) dataSnapshot.getValue(Account.class);     
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
```

Comment: Can I just use CollectionReference cf and then cf.add(Object)?